# How to change default Postgres column numeric create by servicestack to numeric(38,20)

Tags: postgresql, servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

I create PostgreSQL table from ServiceStack ORMLite class

```
[Alias("generaljournalline")]
    public class GeneralJournalLine
    {
        [Required]
        [Alias("debitamount")]
        [Default(typeof(decimal), "0")]
        public decimal DebitAmount { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Alias("creditamount")]
        [Default(typeof(decimal), "0")]
        public decimal CreditAmount { get; set; }
}
```

How to change Postgres columns debitamount, creditamount from numeric(38,6) to numeric(38,20).

Thanks you.

Answer (score 2):

If you can't find another way to do it, the way to do it in PostgreSQL is very simple:

```
 ALTER TABLE generaljournalline ALTER COLUMN debitamount TYPE numeric;
```

That will drop the length constraints altogether.

BTW, I find in accounting software it is usually much easier to store amounts in a single column (- for debit, + for credit) and separate these on extraction.  I am not sure you can do this with an ORM unless you design your tables first, and then views, and use the ORM to interact with the views.  The major advantage is you don't need to use CHECK constraints to handle what happens if someone stores a negative amount.  After all, if someone stores -100 as a debit and -100 as the corresponding credit what does that even mean?